# Crash in pause and start uhd usrp source in windows

Tags: windows, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, usrp, uhd

I created a simple flowgraph :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWN29.jpg
and a gui check box :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPqSP.jpg
and i assigned it to run in properties options like this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnNxn.jpg
when i run it with usrp b210 it's working but when i uncheck checkbox and  check again it crashes.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/spqHz.jpg
I'm using windows 10 and gnuradio version 3.7.13.4.
(I used checkbox to stop and start the flowgraph)
also when I connect gnuradio blocks from my c++ code and I try to use stop of top_block and start it again it crashes.
I also created issue in gnuradio github :
https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/issues/2351

Answer (score 1):

My colleague found answer and i fixed it by adding (|| result.status != LIBUSB_TRANSFER_CANCELLED) to condition that checked if transfer is completed in line 142 of branch rfnoc-devel and i sent a pull request https://github.com/EttusResearch/uhd/pull/289